# this.someFunc.bind(this, a, b, c) Vs () => this.someFunc(a, b, c)

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Whats the difference between using `this.someFunc.bind(this, a, b, c)` vs `() => this.someFunc(a, b, c)`;

> As of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),
> *An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords*

So, the arrow func can get `this` from its scope just as any normal var.

## Does this approach more performant and/or better than the binding option??

Comment: They're equivalent. Use whichever you think looks nicer.

Comment: Although to be fair, I suspect there's a reason the `bind` variant exists.  Monads, perhaps?

Comment: @robert-harvey I don't know much functional programming, So whats `monads` mean in simple term???

Comment: If you use bind, you can change the value of `this` right before invoking the function. With  arrow functions you can't

Comment: `this.someFunc.bind(yourObject, a, b, c)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey `.bind` existed before arrow functions did.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The arrow function is a nicer version of `bind`.

Comment: @aXuser264 very simply, a monad allows you to define processing in multiple steps. So you provide what *steps* you take but the monad takes care about those steps work together about the whole *process*.  A simple example is [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). This is a monadic implementation - `arr.flatMap(f).flatMap(g).flatMap(h)` will produce a single level array, as opposed to nested arrays.